# Running a forloop over a header in R

Tags: r

I am trying to switch from stata to R and need help with a forloop

Context:

I have data(survey questionnaire) with 5 blocks and with 10 questions each. B1B2 <- 2nd question of first block. My rows are people (who can only be in 1 block each) so I have values for that block and NAs for the other variables in the other block. (eg. a person in 3rd block will have observations for B3B1-10 and NA for B1B1-10, B2B1-10 etc.) I am trying to combine all the blocks to B1-10. Heres a header of my data:

```
B1B1  B1B2  B1B3  B1B4  B1B5  B1B6  B1B7  B1B8  B1B9 B1B10  B2B1  B2B2  B2B3  B2B4  B2B5  B2B6  B2B7  B2B8  B2B9 B2B10

  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>

1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     1     2     2     2     2     1     2     1     1     2

2    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     1     1     1     2     2     2     2     1     1     1

3    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA

4    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA

5    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     2     2     2     2     1     2     2     1     1     1

6    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

I got it working for 1 instance using the unite function:

```
data %>% unite("B1", B1B1,B2B1,B3B1,B4B1,B5B1, na.rm = TRUE, remove = FALSE) -> data
```

I want to loop this from B1 to B10 as such

```
for (i in (1:10)){ data %>% unite("paste0("B",i)", paste0("B1B",i),paste0("B2B",i),paste0("B3B",i),paste0("B4B",i),paste0("B5B",i), na.rm = TRUE, remove = FALSE) -> data}
```

but im getting an unexpected symbol error. I think I have a misunderstanding of how forloops work in R and any explanation on why my code doesnt run would be greatly appreciated

Here is my working stata code if it helps:

```
 forvalues i=1(1)10{

   gen b`i'=B1B`i' if B1B`i' != .

   replace b`i'=B2B`i' if B2B`i' != .

   replace b`i'=B3B`i' if B3B`i' != .

   replace b`i'=B4B`i' if B4B`i' != .

   replace b`i'=B5B`i' if B5B`i' != .

  }
```

Comment: What do you mean by blocks? Can you add your data (use the `?dput` function) and specify what format you're trying to achieve?

Comment: by blocks i just mean its split into different variables. I think i worded it poorly but the data I have is split into 5 Variables and im trying to combine them into 1 using an ifelse statement and I need to loop this over 10 sets

Comment: So you have 5 data frames (named "B1B1",...,"B5B1") which have 10 columns each (named "BiB1",...,"BiB10", for each dataframe/i), and you want to join them by rows?

Comment: They are all in the same df.  just different columns in that DF and im trying to combine them into 1. They have a mix of Data and NA (for which the other variables have data)

B1B1
   <dbl>
 1    NA
 2    NA
 3    NA
 4    NA
 5    NA
 6    NA
 7    NA
 8    NA
 9    NA
10     2

B2B1
 2     1
 3    NA
 4    NA
 5     2
 6    NA
 7     2

Comment: Can you edit the post and include your data please? Copy and paste the output from `dput(df)`, where `df` is your data frame.

Comment: Please add data using `dput` or something that we can copy and use. Images are not helpful. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea. Split the dataframe into list of questions and map over each element of the lists.

**Example data:** Three Blocks with 2 Questions

```
df <- data.frame(B1B1 = c(1,2, rep(NA, 4)),
                 B1B2 = c(3,4, rep(NA, 4)),
                 B2B1 = c(NA,NA,5,6,NA,NA),
                 B2B2 = c(NA,NA,7,8,NA,NA),
                 B3B1 = c(rep(NA,4), 1,2),
                 B3B2 = c(rep(NA,4), 3,4))


B1B1 B1B2 B2B1 B2B2 B3B1 B3B2
1    1    3   NA   NA   NA   NA
2    2    4   NA   NA   NA   NA
3   NA   NA    5    7   NA   NA
4   NA   NA    6    8   NA   NA
5   NA   NA   NA   NA    1    3
6   NA   NA   NA   NA    2    4
```

**Code:**

```
library(tidyverse) 

split.default(df, str_extract(names(df), "..$")) %>%
  map_df(~ coalesce(!!! .x))
```

**Result:**

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
     B1    B2
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     3
2     2     4
3     5     7
4     6     8
5     1     3
6     2     4
```